# Remove duplicates from multiple fields and return the queryset in Django

Tags: django

I have query that I send through context as follows:

```
context = { 
    'locations' = TravelData.objects.exclude(Q(from_lat__isnull=True) | Q(from_long__isnull=True) | Q(to_lat__isnull=True) | Q(to_long__isnull=True)).values('from_lat', 'from_long', 'to_lat', 'to_long')
}
```

Here there are multiple values of (`from_lat` and `from_long`) and (`to_lat` and `to_long`). I would like to add the similar values only once i.e., I must check for both `from` values and `to` values at a time and exclude if it is present.

In the frontend I am rendering these locations on a map the co-ordinates of the point will be

```
[from_long, from_lat] or [to_long, to_lat]
```

How can I change the above query to get the most efficient queryset?

Edit:

This is an example of the queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'to_lat': '52.92732', 'to_long': '77.63575', 'from_lat': '52.92415', 'from_long': '77.67229'}, {'to_lat': '52.92768', 'to_long': '77.62664', 'from_lat': '52.96691', 'from_long': '77.74935'}, {'to_lat': '53.047926', 'to_long': '77.597766', 'from_lat': '52.937222', 'from_long': '77.626915'}, {'to_lat': '52.97143', 'to_long': '77.63914', 'from_lat': '52.98999', 'from_long': '77.55332'}, {'to_lat': '52.92732', 'to_long': '77.63575', 'from_lat': '52.92415', 'from_long': '77.67229'}, {'to_lat': '52.92768', 'to_long': '77.62664', 'from_lat': '52.96691', 'from_long': '77.74935'}, {'to_lat': '53.047926', 'to_long': '77.597766', 'from_lat': '52.937222', 'from_long': '77.626915'}, {'to_lat': '52.97143', 'to_long': '77.63914', 'from_lat': '52.98999', 'from_long': '77.55332'}, {'to_lat': '52.97143', 'to_long': '77.63914', 'from_lat': '58.98999', 'from_long': '80.55332'}]>
```

In `<script>` tag of html file a part of code is like this:

```
var locations_object = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
        {% for i in locations %}
            {
                type: 'Feature',
                geometry: {
                    type: 'geojson',
                    coordinates: ["{{i.from_long}}", "{{i.from_lat}}"]
                },
                properties: {
                    title: 'from_locations',
                    description: 'from_locations'
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'Feature',
                geometry: {
                    type: 'geojson',
                    coordinates: ["{{i.to_long}}", "{{i.to_lat}}"]
                },
                properties: {
                    title: 'to_locations',
                    description: 'to_locations'
                }
            },
        {% endfor %}
    ]
};
```

So here there the location with the same co-ordinates values is repeated many times in the database as shown in the `locations` variable of context. But while rendering the map I need it only once. So in the query in the context how can I take the `[to_lat, to_long]` pair and `[from_lat, from_long]` pair only once if it is possible? For eg: In the `locations` of `context` the first four elements are repeated again. So I must consider it only once. Then in the ninth element, the `to_lat` and `to_long` are repeated because it was already present in a previous element. So I must exclude it but `from_lat` and `from_long` is not present in the previous elements. I must consider only this in the ninth element. Similarly for all conditions.

Comment: Could you add some sample data? Are you trying to get all distinct `[from_long, from_lat]` pairs and `[to_long, to_lat]` pairs? 

If `[from_long, from_lat]` is the same for two TravelData objs, which `[to_long, to_lat]` pair do you want to keep?

Comment: I have made edits to the question. Please check it.

Comment: Can you show what the filtered Queryset _should_ resolve to? or what your final values would look like?   It appears that you want all the distinct `[from_long, from_lat]` pairs all the distinct `[to_long, to_lat]` pairs?

Comment: Exactly. I want all those distinct pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to look for distinct TravelData objects based on those 4 fields. You can simply add `.distinct(*fields)` to the query to get what you are looking for.

Since you want distinct values for pairs, I'd suggest doing distinct on one of the pairs in the query, then you could create sets from the values

```
latlong = TravelData.objects.exclude(
        Q(from_lat__isnull=True) | 
        Q(from_long__isnull=True) | 
        Q(to_lat__isnull=True) | 
        Q(to_long__isnull=True)
    ).distinct('from_lat', 'from_long'
).values('from_lat', 'from_long', 'to_lat', 'to_long')

from_pairs = {(x['from_lat'], x['from_long']) for x in latlong}
to_pairs = {(x['to_lat'], x['to_long']) for x in latlong}

all_possible_from_to_pairs = {(from, to) for from in from_pairs for to in to_pairs}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Edit: Updated code after clearer understanding of question.

Comment: I want to get distinct values in pairs. For eg: `distinct of from value pair or to value pair`.